Livewire Installation does not works
I have a blade application and i have installed livewire and published it
but when i use it in there artisan serve it works well but in the localhost (XAMPP) or in the host server
there are some errors in the console and livewire does not work
syntaxerror: unexpected token '>'
my application in
**D:/xampp/htdocs/**5dmaty/demo.elmofid.tech
my config/livewire.php asset_url
'asset_url' => '/5dmaty/demo.elmofid.tech/public/',
I'm expecting that there is an error in the recognizing of the root file.
I have tried some  things
I have commanded
{{-- @livewireScrips --}}
And replaced it by
<script src="/5dmaty/demo.elmofid.tech/public/vendor/livewire/livewire.js" data-csrf="svtJBC64fw6FDa341rsniYXGsg2xXdWCY2Ta9t34" data-update-uri="/livewire/update" data-navigate-once="true"></script> 
so it works well
so i have replaced the asset in the config/livewire.php
'asset_url' => '/5dmaty/demo.elmofid.tech/public/vendor',
but i returns does not work
and get a new error message in the console
http://localhost/5dmaty/demo.elmofid.tech/public/vendor/ net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
so how to make this dynamic
